# Run windows application with a CATIA sub

Tags: vba, catia

I would like to know if is it possible to run a windows application inside of Catia macro. To pop-up or lunch an aplication from Catia macro.

eg. Is it possible to program in VBA a CATIA macro with on click button  that opens an application from windows (eg, Siemens NX, Maya, DDX...)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
    Sub CATMain()

      Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

      WshShell.Run("C:\temp\YourProgramm.exe")

   End Sub
```